# How to disable/enable a context programmatically

Tags: 7

I want to disable contexts programmatically (for automated updates, where a new release of a website needs a context to be disabled).

I manage contexts using Features, but Features doesn't hold the enabled/disabled status of the context.

I can't find a function to change context status programmatically. There's a [support request](https://www.drupal.org/node/822272) but the snippet is not working (nothing happens, context remains the same status).

After some investigation I came across the context_status variable. It seems to hold an array with context names as key and TRUE as value: each of these contexts is disabled. If you edit that variable by unsetting one context, the context becomes enabled.

So it seems the only way to disable/enable a context programmatically is to edit this conext_status.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: BTW, as context_status is a varialbe I can pack it into a feature, and move config from dev sites to prod site, but I can't just pack only one context: this variable seems to hold all system context that are disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's not ideal like you say but at least it's someting we can work with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the context_status to enable/disable contexts.

This variable is an array with context names as key and TRUE as value: each of this context is disabled.

To disable a context: add a new pair to the array like this:

```
$contexts = variable_get('context_status', array());
$contexts['context_name'] = TRUE;
variable_set('context_status', $contexts);
```

To enable a context: unset the context name from context_status.

```
$contexts = variable_get('context_status', array());
unset($contexts['context_name']);
variable_set('context_status', $contexts);
```

Also you can use Features, exporting the context_status to a feature.

Comment: Should be variable_set('context_status', $contexts); rather than 
variable_set('context_name', $contexts);

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may also find [Context Disable Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_disable_context) to be useful. It is a Context plugin that adds a reaction which allows you to disable a context.

Comment: I think is not what I need because this is needed for automatic updates. It's a module to get in mind, thought, thanks for the reference.